# Interactive comments section - Frontend Mentor but with React

Tags: reactjs, frontend

i am trying to make the interactive comments section from Frontend-Mentor challenges but with react and i stacked in the concept of editing replies and comments
dose anyone know how to do it or already have the code on GitHub but with react?
and this a part of my code

```
  function addNewReplies(commentId, content, replyId) {
    if (replyId) {
      const updatedReplies = data
        .find((comment) => comment.id === commentId)
        .replies.map((reply) =>
          reply.id === replyId ? { ...reply, content } : reply
        );
      const updatedComment = {
        ...data.find((comment) => comment.id === commentId),
        replies: updatedReplies,
      };
      const updatedData = data.map((item) =>
        item.id === commentId ? updatedComment : item
      );
      setData(updatedData);
      setSelectedReplyId(null);
      setEditingComment(null);
    } else {
      if (editingComment) {
        const updatedComment = { ...editingComment, content };
        const updatedData = data.map((item) =>
          item.id === editingComment.id ? updatedComment : item
        );
        setData(updatedData);
        setEditingComment(null);
      } else {
        const newReplies = {
          id: Math.random().toString(),
          content,
        };
        setAddReplies([...addReplies, newReplies]);

        const updatedData = data.map((comment) => {
          if (comment.id === commentId) {
            return {
              ...comment,
              replies: [...comment.replies, newReplies],
            };
          }
          return comment;
        });
        setData(updatedData);
        setSelectedReplyId(null);
      }
    }
  }
```